# Sort selected columns by row

Tags: iwork, numbers

In Numbers, how is it possible to sort selected columns by a row?
In the following example I want to sort the columns `B`, `C` and `D` by using the values in row `1`.

[image: example]

So far, I have only found the reverse action (which does what it is supposed to) "sort selected rows by column".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transpose the sheet (Table->Transpose rows and columns), sort, and then transpose back. However you may lose some of the formatting, like column widths and row heights.

Comment: That is a clever workaround!